# Responsively resizing image and background image in tandem

Tags: css, wordpress, image, svg, background

I have [two images](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/12941060?key=c22b6de0c4af72dfade4bfd7b69258fd), a JPG and an SVG, that must be overlaid, the JPG on top of the SVG. They both must resize exactly proportionally as the viewport dimensions change, and not just at specific breakpoints, but continually. The JPG is an image in a figure (`<figure><img/></figure>`) tag set and the SVG is a CSS `background: url(/url/to/image.svg)`. The background image looks like a picture frame around the `<figure>` image, so to keep them looking like they're one unit, it's critical that they each maintain the same aspect ratio as the viewport resizes to any dimension.

I am at a loss as to how to make this happen without either or both getting out of sync and the `<figure>` image is overlapping the background, or the background is getting too large for the `<figure>`. Here's what I've tried.

```
<figure class="outline-img">

    <img 
        width="1024" height="682" 
        src="//localhost:8181/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/istockphoto-1034140728-1024x1024-1.jpeg" 
        class="attachment-large size-large" 
        alt="" 
        loading="lazy" 
        data-src="//localhost:8181/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/istockphoto-1034140728-1024x1024-1.jpeg" 
        data-srcset="//localhost:8181/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/istockphoto-1034140728-1024x1024-1.jpeg 1024w, //localhost:8181/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/istockphoto-1034140728-1024x1024-1-300x200.jpeg 300w, //localhost:8181/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/istockphoto-1034140728-1024x1024-1-768x512.jpeg 768w" 
        data-sizes="(min-width: 960px) 75vw, 100vw"
        srcset="//localhost:8181/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/istockphoto-1034140728-1024x1024-1.jpeg 1024w, //localhost:8181/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/istockphoto-1034140728-1024x1024-1-300x200.jpeg 300w, //localhost:8181/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/istockphoto-1034140728-1024x1024-1-768x512.jpeg 768w" 
        sizes="(min-width: 960px) 75vw, 100vw">
            
</figure>
```

This is the CSS for the background as it's currently constituted:

```
.outline-img {
    padding: 9.4%;
    width: 118%!important;
    background: url(/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/frame.svg);
    background-repeat: space;
    background-position: 50%;
}
```

The weird padding and width values are how I'm currently attempting to "hold" the image within the SVG image's dimensions. Any padding less than that clips the outer edges of the SVG image. Any width less than that makes the image not fit in the SVG's inner edges. And when I resize the browser, the framed image doesn't "stick" to the inner dimensions of the SVG.

I'd love to know if there's an easier way to do this. I tried suggesting making both of these into one JPG image, but the designer is interested in this solution primarily.

Comment: The easiest way would be to put the image in the svg and use the svg inline instead of css background. Can you please edit your question and add the svg for thr frame?

Comment: From my understanding you have an image and a SVG that has to go around the image as some sort of border.
For `outline-img` try to set the padding to a precise measurement (em, px) instead of %, otherwise that will constantly be changing based on the parents size.
As for the image, give it a `max-width: 100%` to prevent it from overflowing, `height: auto` to preserve the aspect ratio. Not sure what your SVG looks like, but tested with random images and this seems to be working for me.
Do you need the SVG to change size based on the image size? In that case this approach wont work.

Comment: Another method you could try, same as before, try giving `outline-img` a precise padding, set it to `position: relative` and add the SVG as an `::after` element. `position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;` to make it cover the whole `div`. This will be on top of the image but if you `z-index: -1` it, it should go under it.
If you could post a screenshot with the desired effect and what it looks like right now it would help to better visualize what's going on.

Comment: +1 do everything in SVG. Then built a W3C standard Web Component, so the user only has to do ``<framed-img ... attributes >``

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I didn't know what Web Components were, so I looked them up. I don't think this will be a good fit for this project as it needs to be a well-accepted approach for all browsers. https://blog.logrocket.com/what-happened-to-web-components/

Comment: @Arthur Thanks. I tried your suggestions in as many ways as I could, but ultimately I couldn't get the svg and the jpg to "lock up" together during viewport resize events.

Comment: @enxaneta I would love to try doing it this way, but the site owner needs to be able to upload their own plain .jpgs of a specific size without any special .svg file handling. The .svg needs to just display behind any image they upload.

Comment: Yes, Web Components need a polyfill in IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the dimension of the image remains same. You can try the following approach.

```css
figure {
  background: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/11/10/16/59/frame-2936877_960_720.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  padding: 5%; /*adjust for your need*/
  width: 30%; /*adjust for your need*/
}
  
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<figure class="outline-img">
    <img width="1000" height="600" 
        src="https://dummyimage.com/600x1000/000/fff"/>
</figure>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This was the code that I needed and that was eluding me.

Answer (score 0):

You could try in 2 different ways:

1. Merge the 2 images together in a unique image, asking the designer again, that would save you time. svg and jpg behave differently
2. if 1. is not an option, convert the .jpg image in .png and choosing the same size of the svg, the image itself will be the same but the transparency will give you the same size. (the important here is actually the aspect ratio)

In both case, add the property [object-fit:contain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) to keep the aspect ratio during scaling and leave width and height set to auto

Going in the direction of using the same images the designer provided will lead to not necessary extra code, plus, even keeping the same aspect ratio, you should take care of the positioning during scale, another hassle which is going to create you problem with particular devices like iPadPro not being exactly targeted from more than one CSS framework around.

Comment: I may have to do #1 as you suggest, but as I noted to enxaneta above, the site owner needs to be able to upload just a plain .jpg without any special handling of the jpg to add the background around it (they don't know or want to use Photoshop for every time they upload a photo). #2 didn't work, either. :(

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the question a little differently.
We have a picture and we need to make it a responsive frame.
But this frame does not have to be one picture.

Instead of one frame, we make a set of images from which, using css, we will assemble a responsive frame around the image.

What you need to do:

Cut the frame into 4 corner pieces.

We also make 4 elements for the top / bottom and left / right edges.

Next, we make a table like this
https://jsfiddle.net/n5zfue27/1/

This solution supports any browser including IE6.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <style type="text/css">
      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
      }

      table {
        table-layout: fixed;

        border-collapse: collapse;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }

      table td {
        padding: 0;
        border: 1px solid black;
      }

      .left-top,
      .left-down,
      .right-top,
      .right-down,
      .left,
      .right {
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        background: red;
      }

      .left,
      .right {
        background-color: #e5e5f7;
        opacity: 0.8;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #444cf7, #444cf7 5px, #e5e5f7 5px, #e5e5f7);
        background-size: 10px 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }

      .center-top,
      .center-down {
        background-color: #e5e5f7;
        opacity: 0.8;
        background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #e5e5f7 50%, #444cf7 50%);
        background-size: 10px 10px;

      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="left-top">

        </td>
        <td class="center-top">

        </td>
        <td class="right-top">

        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="left">

        </td>
        <td class="center"><img style="width: 100%; display: block;" src="https://dunham-bush.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Heron-Tower-London-900x556.jpg"></td>
        <td class="right">

        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="left-down">

        </td>
        <td class="center-down">

        </td>
        <td class="right-down">

        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```